# Partial String on Jinja2 String Variable to EntryField

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

[image]

Alright, I am a bit stumped by this.

I only get the first word, the space escapes I can't get the whole string. It prints to my log just fine, but when I use {{ project_company|safe }} in jinja, I get the first word only. I've looked at documentation and on stackoverflow unable to find an answer to this. I'm guessing its an easy fix and I'm formulating the question wrong.

Record sample: NORTHERN LIGHTS WEB SITE DEVELOPMENT/THE NORTHERN LIGHTS ENDEAVORS/KAREN/SWEENEY/ksweeney@northernlights.com

Example Company: THE NORTHERN LIGHTS ENDEAVORS

Result Company: THE

---

```
if request.method == "POST":
        req = request.form

    if str(req.get("select1")) == 'Project':
            mcon = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+mserver+';DATABASE='+cwdatabase+';UID='+musername+';PWD='+mpassword)
            m = mcon.cursor()
            m.execute(project_query, str(req.get("entry0")))
            mprecords = m.fetchall()

        for record in mprecords:
                project_number = req.get("entry0")
                project_summary = record[1]
                project_company = str(record[2])
                project_name = str(str(record[3]) + ' ' + str(record[4]))
                project_mail = str(record[5])

        return render_template('salesconfirm.html', 
                                project_number=project_number,
                                project_summary=project_summary,
                                project_company=project_company,
                                project_name=project_name,
                                project_mail=project_mail)
__________________________________________________________________

          <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Company</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder={{ project_company|safe }} readonly>
```

---

Log Printout format:

```
output.writelines(str(datetime.now()) + ' - Project Info: ' + str(record[1]) + '/' + str(record[2]) + '/' + str(record[3]) + '/' + str(record[4]) + '/' + str(record[5]) + "\n")
```

Log Output:

```
2020-06-05 09:21:29.214032 - Project Info: NORTHERN LIGHTS WEB SITE
```

DEVELOPMENT/THE NORTHERN LIGHTS ENDEAVORS/KAREN/SWEENEY/ksweeney@northernlights.com

Comment: I meant Could you add a sample record from mprecords ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was quite easy.

Adding quotes before and after the variable in Jinja fixes it

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ project_company|safe }}" readonly>
```